Invalid syntax error when running mpiexec
I'm trying to write some code in PyCharm using mpi4py (MPI). But I get an error when executing "mpiexec -n 4 python filename.py" in PyCharm console. It says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", and "4" is highlighted.
I reinstalled mpi4py and MS MPI but it didn't work. Putting another number instead of "4" also didn't help. I tried to use mpirun, but there was the same error.
Running that from cmd didn't work either, even though I specified a file path.
Code itself runs with no errors (when hitting a green triangle).

according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/high-performance-computing/mpiexec?view=hpc19-ps the syntax is mpiexec /np 4 ...

Thank you, but I'm still confused, because it's a bit different from I've read here: https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.0.x/www1/mpiexec.html

MS MPI is a MPICH derivative, but you should not assume everything is 100% compatible.

I've tried both -n and /np, but it didn't work anyway.

then copy/paste the command line and error message.
